# how can I calculate the sum of my top n records in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-8.5

I m using report tab -> group sort expert-> top n to get top n record but i m getting sum of value in report footer for all records

I want only sum of value of top n records...

In below image i have select top 3 records but it gives sum of all records.
  [image]

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't have much experience with the horror that is crystal reports but even so I would have thought that in this context Sum is the wrong function to be using.  Is there not a max function that you could call?

Comment: @ Dom Sinclair In crystal report there is option like maximum record per page so if i select 5 record then it will display 5 record on each page.

Answer (score 0):

The group sort expert (and the record sort expert too) intervenes in your final result after the total summary is calculated. It is unable to filter and remove rows, in the same way an ORDER BY clause of SQL cannot effect the SELECT's count result (this is a job for WHERE clause). As a result, your summary will always be computed for all rows of your detail section and, of course, for all your group sums.

If you have in mind a specific way to exlude specific rows in order to appear the appropriate sum the you can use the Select Expert of Crystal Reports to remove rows.

Alternatively (and I believe this is the best way), I would make all the necessary calculations in the SQL command and I would sent to the report only the Top 3 group sums (then you can get what you want with a simple total summary of these 3 records)

Something like that

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
 DEP_NAME varchar(50),
 MINVAL int,
 RMAVAL int,
 NETVAL int
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
 SELECT TOP 3 
 T.DEP_NAME ,T.MINVAL,T.RMAVAL,T.NETVAL 
 FROM
 (SELECT DEP_NAME AS DEP_NAME,SUM(MINVAL) AS MINVAL,SUM(RMAVAL) AS 
RMAVAL,SUM(NETVAL) AS NETVAL 
 FROM YOURTABLE
 GROUP BY DEP_NAME) AS T
ORDER BY MINVAL DESC

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```